# Firebase permission for storage function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to trigger my function on specific path in storage bucket using:

```
exports.generateThumbnail = functions.storage.bucket("users").object().onChange(event => {});
```

When I try to deploy it, console shows:

```
functions[generateThumbnail]: Deploy Error: Insufficient permissions to (re)configure a trigger (permission denied for bucket users). Please, give owner permissions to the editor role of the bucket and try again.
```

How can I do that? Do I nedd to setup IAM or bucket permission or maybe something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the issue is that you're trying to reference a bucket named "users" rather than filtering on an object prefix.

What you want is:

```
exports.generateThumbnail = functions.storage.object().onChange(event => {
  if (object.name.match(/users\//)) {
    // do whatever you want in the filtered expression!
  }
});
```

Eventually we want to make prefix filtering available so you can do `object("users")`, but currently you have to filter in your function like above.

Comment: but this tigger is gonna be called everytime any change happens in the storage right? wont that create excess load ?

Comment: It will spin up the function at present, and there's unfortunately no way to change that. As mentioned, we're looking into integrating prefix filtering so it doesn't.