# Read from firebase storage and write to firestore using firebase functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I had tried this typescript code

```js
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

import serviceAccount from "/Users/300041370/Downloads/serviceKey.json";

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
});

const buckObj = functions.storage.bucket("myBucket").object();
export const onWikiWrite = buckObj.onFinalize(async (object) => {
  const filePath = object.name ?? "test.json";
  const bucket = admin.storage().bucket("myBucket");

  bucket.file(filePath).download().then((data) => {
    const contents = data[0];
  data = {"key": "value"};
const doc = admin.firestore().collection("myCollection").doc();
doc.set(data);
  });
});
```

but this gave me following error

> "status":{"code":7,"message":"Insufficient permissions to (re)configure a trigger (permission denied for bucket myBucket). Please, give owner permissions to the editor role of the bucket and try again.

I had asked this [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68119617/insufficient-permissions-issue-while-deploying-a-firebase-function) but it got closed as duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42854857/firebase-permission-for-storage-function). It basically said, `storage.bucket("myBucket")` feature is not supported and that I'll have to instead use `match` for limiting this operation to files in this specific bucket/folder. Hence, I tried this

```js
const buckObj = functions.storage.object();
export const onWikiWrite = buckObj.onFinalize(async (object) => {
  if (object.name.match(/myBucket\//)) {
    const fileBucket = object.bucket;
    const filePath = object.name;
    const bucket = admin.storage().bucket(fileBucket);
    bucket.file(filePath).download().then((data) => {
      const contents = data[0];
      const doc = admin.firestore().collection("myCollection").doc();
      const data = {content: contents}
      doc.set(data);
    });
  }
});
```

I am still facing the same issue. I'll repeat that here:

> "status":{"code":7,"message":"Insufficient permissions to (re)configure a trigger (permission denied for bucket myBucket). Please, give owner permissions to the editor role of the bucket and try again.

Comment: Normally, since version 1.0 of the Firebase SDK for Cloud Functions `firebase-admin` shall be initialized [without any parameters within the Cloud Functions runtime](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff?authuser=0#sdk_changes_that_affect_all_background_non-http_functions).

Comment: Dearest @RenaudTarnec, I wouldn't even imagine, this was the issue. Basically, before this happened due to some other issue, post which I added this parameter to admin call. Then the earlier issue got solved and this admin-parameter might have started giving the same issue.
Anyway, thanks 

Comment: Glad I could help you @kamalbanga. See my response which points out an important aspect of Cloud Functions lifecycle management: you need to return a JavaScript promise when all the asynchronous processing is complete.

Comment: Yeah looking at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since version 1.0 of the Firebase SDK for Cloud Functions, `firebase-admin` shall be [initialized without any parameters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff?authuser=0#sdk_changes_that_affect_all_background_non-http_functions) within the Cloud Functions runtime.

The following should work (I've removed the check on `filePath`):

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
admin.initializeApp();

export const onWikiWrite = functions.storage
  .object()
  .onFinalize(async (object) => {
    const fileBucket = object.bucket;
    const filePath = object.name;
    const bucket = admin.storage().bucket(fileBucket);
    return bucket
      .file(filePath)
      .download()
      .then((data) => {
        const contents = data[0];
        return admin
          .firestore()
          .collection('myCollection')
          .add({ content: contents });
      });
  });
```

---

Note that we return the [chain of promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#chained_promises) returned by the asynchronous Firebase methods. It is key, in a Cloud Function which performs asynchronous processing (also known as "background functions") to return a JavaScript promise when all the asynchronous processing is complete.

We also use the `add()` method instead of doing `doc().set()`.

---

Finally, when checking the value of the `filePath`, be aware of the fact that there is actually no concept of folder or subdirectory in Cloud Storage (See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65483628/firebase-admin-sdk-cant-upload-to-storage-bucket-folder/65483907#65483907)).

Comment: BTW, is my way of matching files in the bucket `myBucket` correct?

Comment: Not sure. See my last update. It's a classical error to mix-up Bucket name and "folder" name. I suggest you do `console.log(filePath)` to really find the correct value.